# Deducing template arguments during partial ordering when parameters are function parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, overload-resolution

> N4527 14.8.2.4 [temp.deduct.partial]
>
> 3 The types used to determine the ordering depend on the context in which the partial ordering is done:
>
> (3.1) — In the context of a function call, the types used are those function parameter types for which the function call has arguments.
>
> (3.2) — In the context of a call to a conversion function, the return types of the conversion function templates are used.
>
> (3.3) — In other contexts (14.5.6.2) the function template’s function type is used.
>
> 4 Each type nominated above from the parameter template and the corresponding type from the argument
>   template are used as the types of `P` and `A`.
>
> 8 If `A` was transformed from a function parameter pack and `P` is not a parameter pack, type deduction fails.
>   Otherwise, using the resulting types `P` and `A`, the deduction is then done as described in 14.8.2.5. If `P`
>   is a function parameter pack, the type `A` of each remaining parameter type of the argument template is
>   compared with the type `P` of the declarator-id of the function parameter pack. Each comparison deduces
>   template arguments for subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by the function
>   parameter pack. If deduction succeeds for a given type, the type from the argument template is considered
>   to be at least as specialized as the type from the parameter template. 
>   [ Example:

```
template<class... Args>           void f(Args... args);        // #1
template<class T1, class... Args> void f(T1 a1, Args... args); // #2
template<class T1, class T2>      void f(T1 a1, T2 a2);        // #3

f();        // calls #1
f(1, 2, 3); // calls #2
f(1, 2);    // calls #3; non-variadic template #3 is more
            // specialized than the variadic templates #1 and #2
```

Why `f(1, 2, 3);` calls #2?

I need more details including:

1 Which context is it?

2 What are the transformed froms?
 e.g. the transformed from of #1 is `void (U)` , `void (U...)` or other form?(`U` means an unique type)

> 14.5.6.2 [temp.func.order]/p3
>
> To produce the transformed template, for each type, non-type, or template template parameter (including
>   template parameter packs (14.5.3) thereof) synthesize a unique type, value, or class template respectively
>   and substitute it for each occurrence of that parameter in the function type of the template.

3 What are the types of `P` and `A` used in deduction? e.g

```
template <class T> void f(T);
int a = 1;
f(a);//P = T, A = int
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why `f(1, 2, 3);` calls #2?

There's a lot of questions in your question (one question per question please!), so I will stick to that one. First, we perform template deduction. #3 fails, but #1 and #2 succeed:

```
template<class... Args>
void f(Args... args);        // #1, with Args = {int, int, int}
template<class T1, class... Args> 
void f(T1 a1, Args... args); // #2, with T1 = int, Args = {int, int}
```

Both functions take three `int`s by value, so all the normal tiebreakers in overload resolution fail to resolve the ambiguity. So we get to the very last one:

> Given these definitions, a viable function `F1` is defined to be a better function than another viable function `F2` if for all arguments `i`, ICS<sub>i</sub>(`F1`) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICS<sub>i</sub>(`F2`), and then
>   — [...]
>   — `F1` and `F2` are function template specializations, and the function template for `F1` is more specialized
>   than the template for `F2` according to the partial ordering rules described in 14.5.6.2.

The rules are:

**Step 1**: synthesize types [temp.func.order]:

> To produce the transformed template, for each type, non-type, or template template parameter (including
>   template parameter packs (14.5.3) thereof) synthesize a unique type, value, or class template respectively
>   and substitute it for each occurrence of that parameter in the function type of the template.

So we have:

```
void f(Pack1... args);         // #1
void f(U2 a1, Pack2... args);  // #2
```

**Step 2**: perform deduction as described in [temp.deduct.partial]. The context we're in is a function call, so we use the types for which the function call has arguments.

First, we try to deduce #2 from #1. That is, we try to match (`T1, Args...`) against `(Pack1...)`. The first part is then `P = T1, A = Pack1...`. We have:

> If A was transformed from a function parameter pack and P is not a parameter pack, type deduction fails.

So deducing #2 from #1 fails, so the argument `Args...` is not at least as specialized as `T1, Args...`.

Next, we try to deduce #1 from #2. That is, we try to match `(Args...)` against `(U2, Pack2...)`. That succeeds, so `T1, Args...` is at least as specialized as `Args...`.

Since #2 is at least as specialized as #1 and #1 is not at least as specialized as #2, we can say that #2 is more specialized:

> Function template `F` is at least as specialized as function template `G` if, for each pair of types used to
>   determine the ordering, the type from `F` is at least as specialized as the type from `G`. `F` is more specialized
>   than `G` if `F` is at least as specialized as `G` and `G` is not at least as specialized as `F`.

The more specialized template is preferred, so we call #2.