# Function template argument deduction with variadic class template as function call parameter

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

All the examples are from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_type).

Specifically,

```
template<class...> struct Tuple { };
template<          class... Types> void g(Tuple<Types ...>);        // #1
// template<class T1, class... Types> void g(Tuple<T1, Types ...>);    // #2
template<class T1, class... Types> void g(Tuple<T1, Types& ...>);   // #3

g(Tuple<>());                     // calls #1
g(Tuple<int, float>());           // calls #2
g(Tuple<int, float&>());          // calls #3
g(Tuple<int>());                  // calls #3
```

With `#2` uncommented, g()'s are resolved as described in the comments. What surprises me is that if I comment out the `#2` line, the g()'s calls are resolved as follows:

```
g(Tuple<>());                     // calls #1
g(Tuple<int, float>());           // calls **#1 ???? why not #3????**
g(Tuple<int, float&>());          // calls #3
g(Tuple<int>());                  // calls #3
```

From the following examples and explanations below I can't see why `g(Tuple<int, float>());` can't resolved to `#3`. It is the direction application of the following two rules:

> If a parameter pack appears as the last P, then the type P is matched against the type A of each remaining argument of the call. Each match deduces the template arguments for the next position in the pack expansion.

```
template<class ... Types> void f(Types& ...);
void h(int x, float& y) {
const int z = x;
f(x, y, z); // P=Types&..., A1=x: deduces the first member of Types... to int
            // P=Types&..., A2=y: deduces the second member of Types... to float
            // P=Types&..., A3=z: deduces the third member of Types... to const int
           // calls f<int, float, const int>
```

> If P has one of the forms that include a template parameter list `<T>` or `<I>`, then each element Pi of that template argument list is matched against the corresponding template argument Ai of its A. If the last Pi is a pack expansion, then its pattern is compared against each remaining argument in the template argument list of A. A trailing parameter pack that is not otherwise deduced, is deduced to an empty parameter pack.

Comment: How can you deduce `Types` in `Types&...` if one of the target types is not a reference (`float`)?

Comment: There is no value of `Types...` that will make `Types&...` equal to `float`.

Comment: @aschepler I hope the rule is that simple. But when P is of the form <T>, it is broken up as I quoted. So what ends up being deducted are the following pairs (T1/int ) and (Types&.../float). And as the example code I quoted, it is Ok to have P=Types&... and A= float: the result is that the first member of the pack Types... is simply float

Comment: @Columbo If what you are saying is correct,  how did the example code f(x,y,z) work? the function parameters are all references but none of x, y and z are references.

Comment: @aschepler @ Columbo can you guys also comment on a related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/33426038/1021388?

Comment: Well, what does your compiler say if you comment out #1 and #2 and try `g(Tuple<int,float>());`?  Is the question really why that doesn't compile?

Comment: I think I know why I got it misunderstand. The part "If P has one of the forms that include a template parameter list <T> or <I>..." is not recursive (meaning that the parameter/argument pairs are matched verbatim, not as function calls analysis). All the transformations done on function parameters and arguments are not re-done for this part of the analysis. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a misconception here between your two examples. In the 2nd example with `f`, you are deducing reference *arguments* to a function. In the 1st example with `g`, you are deducing reference *template parameters* to an argument to a function. The latter must match exactly, but the former is deduced against the referred types. They are not the same.

---

In your fist example,

```
g(Tuple<int, float>());
```

cannot call `g(Tuple<T1, Types&...>)`. The template deduction process is about picking a deduced argument type that is identical to the called argument type. There are some exceptions (for referenced cv-qualifications, pointers, derived classes, arrays, functions), but none of those apply here. We simply need to pick `T1` and `Types...` such that `Tuple<T1, Types&...>` is the same type as `Tuple<int, float>`. This is impossible as there is no such pack `Types...` for which `Types&...` is `{float}`, since `float` is not a reference!

So once you comment out (2), there's only one viable candidate: (1).

---

On the other hand,

```
template<class ... Types> void f(Types& ...);
void h(int x, float& y) {
    const int z = x;
    f(x, y, z);
}
```

Here, `Types&...` is actually the type of the parameter itself (rather than a template argument of it), so (temp.deduct.call):

> If P is a reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction.

We deduce `Types...` to match the arguments. This succeeds because all the arguments are lvalues, and we simply pick `{int, float, const int}`.

Comment: Thanks! You confirmed my re-interpretation in the comment above under OP. So basically template `parameter/argument` pair deduction has to match exactly, whereas function call `parameter/argument` pair undergo some transformations and exceptions during matching. Right?

Comment: @Rich There is only parameter/argument pair matching. Just that in one of your examples, the way you do that matching is match the template arguments.